# How to delete git commits but keep changes?

Tags: git

I committed a very large file together with my regular files. I want to make the remote forget the commit I just did but all the tutorials I find talk about reverting to a previous commit, which will make me loss all my changes. I just want to delete the commit but keep the changes, then I can add the large file to gitignore and push the changes

Comment: 1) Make a backup of your repository, then try 2) `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: The commit contains the changes, so there's no way around deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your want to delete your last commit which contains your new large file (I assume you have only this file in your commit), so:

**A-** if you can force commit on remote repository (and if you won't make a mess to your colleagues in a case they have already pulled your commit):

1- Delete the last commit without losing changes: `git reset HEAD~1`

2- Add your large file to `.gitignore`, your can add it in
    `.git/info/exclude` instead, to ignore the file **locally** in your
    working copy.

3- Commit `.gitignore` if your have changed it.

4- `git push --force origin <your_branch>`

**B-** if you can't/won't use `git push --force`:

1- Make Copy of your file somewhere outside of your local repository.

2- Revert the last commit:
`git revert HEAD`

3- Bring your file back to your local repository.

4- Add it to your `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` (as you like!).

5- `git push origin <your_branch>`

Comment: Agree about your approach here, but keep in mind with B the large file will still be cloned whenever the repository is cloned in the future, as it exists in the revision history now.